# I want to draw a random circle or oval shape on my image taken from camera

Tags: java, android

My question is that I will take an image from camera and it will be sent to an image view in an activity. After that I need to draw a circle or rectangle on the image.it should be a free hand. I mean I want to draw at any size. Then that image should be saved. I tried to put the image to the view but I am unable to draw on it. I am new to android. Can anyone help me out of this?

```
  //This is camera Intent

        camera =(Button)findViewById(R.id.camera_button);
        camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rl_main.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                rl_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Intent intent =new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
                // start the image capture Intent
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);


            }


        });

   @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case SPEECH_RECOGNITION_CODE: {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                    ArrayList<String> result = data
                            .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    String text = result.get(0);
                    description.setText(text);
                }
                break;
            }

            case REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE:
            {
                if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    loadimage();
                }
            }


        }

    }

    private void loadimage() {

        if (fileUri!=null){

            Bitmap myImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath());

            File file = new File(fileUri.getPath());
            BitmapFactory.Options bounds =new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bounds.inSampleSize = 4;
            bounds.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            String path = file.getPath();
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path,bounds);

            BitmapFactory.Options opts =new BitmapFactory.Options();
            opts.inSampleSize = 4;
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path,opts);
            ExifInterface exif =null;

            try {
                exif =new ExifInterface(path);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String orientString = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
            int orientation = orientString != null ? Integer.parseInt(orientString) :  ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL;

            int rotationAngle = 0;
            if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90){
                rotationAngle = 90;
            }
            if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180){
                rotationAngle = 180;
            }
            if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270){
                rotationAngle = 270;
            }


            final Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.setRotate(rotationAngle, (float) bm.getWidth() / 2, (float) bm.getHeight() / 2);
            Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bounds.outWidth,bounds.outHeight, matrix, true);


            /*    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
               matrix.postRotate(90);
                Bitmap rotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(myImg, 0, 0, myImg.getWidth(), myImg.getHeight(),
                        matrix, true);*/
            Bitmap mutableBitmap = rotatedBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);


            camera_IV.setImageBitmap(mutableBitmap);

            DisplayMetrics displaymetrics =new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
            int height1 = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
            int width1 = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
            Log.e("MA", "Height= " + height1 + " " + width1);
            paint = new Paint();
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
            //  paint.setTextSize(25);
            paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            originalBitmap =Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(rotatedBitmap, camera_IV.getWidth(), camera_IV.getHeight(), false);

            imageBitmap = originalBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, true);

            camera_IV.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent dragEvent) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
            camera_IV.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {



            });



            BitmapFactory.Options myOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            myOptions.inDither = true;
            myOptions.inScaled = false;
            myOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;// important
            myOptions.inPurgeable = true;



            mPaint = new Paint();
            mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mPaint.setDither(true);
            mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            // mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);

        }


    }
```

`